# How to start qemu virtual machines at boot time?

Tags: qemu

What are the best practices to start *qemu* hosts automatically at boot time under Debian Wheezy? I do not use any abstraction layer like *libvirt* and start my virtual machines manually with for example:

```
qemu -enable-kvm -hda /root/1.raw -device e1000,mac=de:ad:be:ef:69:01,netdev=net0 -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=tap1 -display vnc=:1 -k sv -daemonize
```

A custom init script?

Comment: I would be inclined to say that these days using an abstraction layer such as _libvirt_ would be best practice. You don't have to use the GUI. Really.

Comment: Why is that so? To me KISS approach seems to be better. At least up to few-dozen virtual machines.

Comment: I'd completely agree. Running `virsh autostart {machine}` once would have been a really simple approach to answering your question.

Answer (score 2):

An init script would be the way to go. Use of modprobe to ensure your kvm modules are loaded into the kernel may be unnecessary since they may already be loaded but if you run into problems you can always add it to your script.